# Apache Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool bad performance on batch \ bulk inserts

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, bulkinsert, jdbc-pool

I have recently incorporated the Apache Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool to my application (using MySQL DB). I tried using Apache DBCP before, but didn't like its results, and the tomcat implementation seemed to fit my needs even though I run a standalone java application and don't use tomcat at all.

Recently, I encountered a huge performance problem when executing batch (aka bulk ) insert queries.

I have a flow in which I insert ~2500 records to a table in a batched fashion. It takes forever when using the jdbc connection pool, compared to a few seconds when reverting back to opening a connection for each query (no pooling).

I wrote a small application that inserts 30 rows to the same table. It takes 12 seconds when pooling, and ~ 800 millis when not pooling.

Prior to using the connection pool, I used `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource` as my DataSource. The connection was configured with the following line:

```
dataSource.setRewriteBatchedStatements(true);
```

I'm quite sure that this is the core difference between the two approaches, but couldn't find an equivalent parameter in jdbc-pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySql JDBC driver does not support batch operations. RewriteBatchedStatement is the best that you can get. Here the code from mysql [PreparedStatement.java](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java):

```
 try {
            statementBegins();

            clearWarnings();

            if (!this.batchHasPlainStatements && this.connection.getRewriteBatchedStatements()) {

                if (canRewriteAsMultiValueInsertAtSqlLevel()) {
                    return executeBatchedInserts(batchTimeout);
                }

                if (this.connection.versionMeetsMinimum(4, 1, 0) && !this.batchHasPlainStatements && this.batchedArgs != null
                        && this.batchedArgs.size() > 3 /* cost of option setting rt-wise */) {
                    return executePreparedBatchAsMultiStatement(batchTimeout);
                }
            }

            return executeBatchSerially(batchTimeout);
        } finally {
            this.statementExecuting.set(false);

            clearBatch();
        }
```

It is one of the reason why I do not like MySql and prefer Postgres

EDIT:

You should combine connection pool, batch operation, and RewriteBatchedStatement option. You can set RewriteBatchedStatement option through jdbc url parameter: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/mydb?rewriteBatchedStatements=true`

Comment: 10x for the answer. I don't mind if the batch operations are "semi" pure as long as they take a minimum amount of time, just like I demonstrated at the bottom of my question. I'm looking for the equivalent of these "semi" pure batches in the jdbc-pool (or any other pool for that matter).

Comment: You should add parameter `?rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to jdbc url.